# MySql: Get latest record then group alphabetically

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM form_advertisers fa
INNER JOIN form_settings fs USING(form_id)
WHERE fa.advertiser_id = $adv_id
GROUP BY fs.ukip_title_id
ORDER BY fs.form_title ASC, fs.form_id DESC
```

Simplified:

```
SELECT form_id, form_title FROM form_advertisers
WHERE advertiser_id = 135
GROUP BY ukip_title_id
ORDER BY form_title ASC, form_id DESC
```

But this is only ordering the result set by `form_title` then `form_id`, whereas I need it to find the most recent `form_id` for each `$adv_id` ***then*** order them alphabetically.

I read about the keyword `HAVING`, and also (what looked like) a `SELECT` inside a `SELECT`, but it's really quite confusing. Can anyone get my query working, and possibly even find the time to explain what it's doing?

Results (ordered alphabetically, but not the latest form_id):

```
form_id   form_title
4         Automotive Testing
756       Electric & Hybrid Marine
22        Electric & Hybrid Vehicle
11        Engine
21        European Automotive
721       Magnetics
24        Professional MotorSport
220       Transmission
```

Suggestion Results (`form_id DESC` before `form_title ASC`) (still incorrect as only sorts output):

```
form_id   form_title
756       Electric & Hybrid Marine
721       Magnetics
220       Transmission
24        Professional MotorSport
22        Electric & Hybrid Vehicle
21        European Automotive
11        Engine
4         Automotive Testing
```

Expected results (latest `form_id`):

```
form_id   form_title
610       Automotive Testing
756       Electric & Hybrid Marine
940       Electric & Hybrid Vehicle
912       Engine
132       European Automotive
720       Magnetics
780       Professional MotorSport
332       Transmission
```

Complete data:

```
4   Automotive Testing International
11  Engine Technology International
22  Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
21  European Automotive Components
24  Professional Motorsport World
25  Automotive Testing International
43  Engine Technology International
57  Engine Technology International
62  European Automotive Components
78  European Automotive Components
82  Engine Technology International
92  Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International...
106 Engine Technology International
109 Professional Motorsport World
118 Engine Technology International
132 European Automotive Components
144 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International...
218 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
220 Transmission Technology International
226 Engine Technology International
252 Engine Technology International
278 Engine Technology International
284 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
330 Engine Technology International
332 Transmission Technology International
358 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
392 Engine Technology International
428 Engine Technology International
434 Professional Motorsport World
458 Engine Technology International
470 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
570 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
584 Engine Technology International
610 Automotive Testing International
618 Engine Technology International
638 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
720 Magnetics Technology International
752 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
764 Engine Technology International
780 Professional Motorsport World
756 Electric & Hybrid Marine Technology International
800 Engine Technology International
820 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
852 Engine Technology International
912 Engine Technology International
940 Electric & Hybrid Vehicle Technology International
```

Comment: move `fs.form_id DESC` to be first in the order by statement. Because you want to apply that ordering before the alphabetization.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: The problem is not with the ordering of the data I'm getting out, but with finding the correct data in the database in the first place.

Comment: do you have a date column?, also can you provide some sample data?

Comment: The data column is unfortunately inaccurate, as it changes on record edit (not my idea). The `form_id` is accurate however, as the higher the number, the newer the record.

Comment: did you try to put fs.form_id DESC to the first ordering?... its kinda difficult to help when we can't see some data to know what were working with

Comment: Data added. I tried putting `form_id DESC` first, but it only sorts the outputted data by `form_id`, and not the data in the database before outputting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...... let me know if it works:

```
SELECT * FROM( 
    SELECT form_id as form_id,
        mag_logo_url, 
        cover_date, 
        fs.ukip_title_id as title_id, 
        fs.form_title as form_title 
    FROM form_advertisers fa 
    INNER JOIN form_settings fs 
    USING ( form_id ) 
    WHERE fa.advertiser_id =135 
    ORDER BY fs.form_id DESC 
)as temp 
GROUP BY title_id 
ORDER BY form_title ASC , form_id DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, it just orders the same data, doesn't find the most recent `form_id`s.

Comment: what about your other table you are joining?

Comment: All the other table contains is the `advertiser_id` that I need. In this case, `135`.

Comment: so is advertiser id 135 related to the 940 id? seems like that is the filter that is messing it up

Comment: All of these records are for `advertiser_id = 135`. Add `135` to the same table and remove the `INNER JOIN` if you so wish. Simplified query added to the initial post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49764/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-matthew-peckham)

Comment: John... I just found a problem with this edited solution. It finds the `MAX(form_id)` no problem... but the other columns are still using the first row, not the last!